# where can I see the change logs for the raspbian buster repositories

Tags: raspbian-buster, pip

Pip3 was broken after I performed an update today,  I saw what I think were two releases within hours of each other, the second changed the behaviour of pip3 but it was still broken.

Is there a way to see the changes to the repos, something similar to git log?  I would like to find out if the updates broke pip3 or it was something else.

Comment: `I performed an update today`... **What** did you update?? The system (`apt update`), or Python, or PiP... what? Do you know where the `git logs` are located? IIRC, `git` has a feature to "roll back" an update. Please (re-)read [How to ask a good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I performed apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, the title of the post refrenced the change logs for buster repositories.   I did not ask where the git logs are located, I asked if there was a way to see the changes which were made to the repositories used by apt.   Are you telling me that apt actually uses git and I can rollback?  This doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Your question said, `"...something similar to git log?"` In the absence of an indication of what kind of `update` you performed, I took that as you saying that you were looking for the git logs.

Comment: No worries :)  I guess this is more of a question about the apt package management process for the Pi, do you know where I can find this information or how they are controlled it so I can find out more ?

Comment: It is unclear what makes you think "pip3 but it was still broken". pip is part of the python package and pip3 hasn't changed since release - it is dated 2021-07-17

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know, It must be the installation which is corrupt.  No point in posting the stack trace from pip3, I have been down that rabbit hole.  I will just put a new image the SD card and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/ contains releases

Older OS in http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/archive/

These have `.info` files.

Not sure that there is a changelog for updates, although the `git` of the repositories would have this.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find out what had changed on the system which broke pip, removing and reinstalling both python and pip hasn't fixed it so I thought it must have been something changed in the apt repos, hence I was looking for a change log.  I think I will just reinstall from the old buster image and retry the updates.  Hopefully, that will fix it.